# c# minimal code for creating instance on-the-fly

Tags: c#, properties, initialization, on-the-fly

Suppose we want to create a collection of services, which may or may be not used by:

```
  class ServiceCollection {
     public MyService MyService = new MyService(arg1,arg2,...);
     public MySecondService MySecondService = new MySecondService(arg1,arg2,...);
     ...
```

As we don't know if a service instance will be used or not - we wanted to create a service instance on-the-fly:

```
  class ServiceCollection {
     private MyService _MyService = null;
     public MyService MyService { 
        get {
           if (_MyService==null) _MyService = new MyService(arg1,arg2,...);
           return _MyService;
       }
     }
```

It is a requirement in case the user code refers to a service twice - the same service instance should be used. As the code above is ... kinda long ... I wonder is the following resulution is correct or not:

```
  class ServiceCollection {
     private MyService _MyService = null;
     public MyService MyService => _MyService = _MyService ?? new MyService(arg1, ...);
```

Or does any other (more elegant and short) solution exist for this simple problem?

Comment: You are looking for a Singleton. There can be a lot more to it dependig on your needs.

Comment: have come across this kind of code in a medium-large c# codebase, so i think its okay.

Comment: It is not a kind of singleton - or I missed something. There can be several instances of  MyService, but in this collection there can be zero or one only. We just dont want to create another one when one is created - suppose creation of a service is a heavy operation. And the question is not on "how to create only one instance" but how to write a short and elegant code to retrieve and re-use of an instance which is created on-demand only.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to understand the architecture. In general, you can load different services, on the fly, with dependency injection. So I don't see a reason to go through the difficulty you are trying.

Or, are you trying to load balance on your side of the equation? If so, why?

There are two potential ideas here.

1. I don't want to load a service until it is used
2. I want to balance the load between multiple services

Architecturally, the first is great for loading dependencies via injection. The latter is better if you have the API team provide the scale for you.

Am I missing something?

Comment: There are two ways to achieve such a goal you described. One way is to configure and use dependency injection system when you want to "replace" a service to a faked one or something else. Another way to use service collections, where you can build an "environment" with some faked and some real ones, and gives this collection to the user code to use them. Advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: When a service constuctor get another argument - all the codes around must be modified as well as the DI system. In this approach the creation of a service is centralized into this collection. On-demand. It's an advantage - or I think it is.